# Unable to map all paths to URIs

Tags: 2011, publishing

I know there are similar posts regarding same issue. However none of them seems to helping me fixing this issue.

Issue is when I tries to publish/open page, I got the following error:

> Unable to map all paths to URIs.
>
> ---
>
> Content Manager
>   StackTrace:  Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert() 
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String) 
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String) 
>   SomeName.Tridion.Templating.HSTL.RenderInlineComponentPresentations.GetComponentTemplateUri(String,String)
>   SomeName.Tridion.Templating.HSTL.RenderInlineComponentPresentations.ProcessMatch(String,Match)
>   SomeName.Tridion.Templating.HSTL.RenderInlineComponentPresentations.Transform(Engine,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine,Package,String,String)
>   Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template,Package)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderedItem,RenderContext)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,String)
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderComponentPresenation(UserContext,String,String,String)
>   UtilitiesPublish.RenderComponentPresentation 
>   ComponentPresentation.Render  Component.Render  Request.Render

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unable to map all paths to URIs` means "You gave me a WebDav Url but it doesn't point to anything".

Looking at the stack trace, I'd think that the creators of that code (SomeName) may have a better understanding of why it failed. In particular, it looks like this class `SomeName.Tridion.Templating.HSTL.RenderInlineComponentPresentations.GetComponentTemplateUri(String,String)` is trying to find a Component Template to apply, likely based on a WebDav Url - but the WebDav Url is either incorrect or the template doesn't actually exist.

Given that this is probably a TBB, I'd open this template in Template Builder and try to figure out which WebDav Url it's looking for. With a bit a luck, it may be a parameter in the TBB.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to hide the company name unless you owns the company or have full rights on the code. Open your TBB in Template Builder -> Verify all the parameters (which may be pre-filled with default values) -> Change the values in parameters which are appropriate to you.

If it still does not give you fair idea, try to get the code of the C# TBB and debug that to find out error.

Comment: Not sure why you are suggesting to hide the company name, it is an implementer and as a customer I would expect they do have access to the source code of the TBBs used in their implementation. But anyways, I don't think there is a requirement of hiding that name here, you wouldn't do that with any other company either if you are using their products.

Comment: Still - probably better to contact them directly....